# Zoom in/out on a wx.Panel

Tags: python, wxpython

Is there a general way for zooming in/out on a `wx.Panel` (all its content should be zoomed as well) ?

Is it possible to define a new `sizer` type that would provide this feature ?

Comment: What do you mean by "its content should be zoomed"?  A sizer can change the size of the contained windows (that's basically the point of sizers), but, for example, button labels will stay the same size.

Comment: I mean that the content should be rescaled according to the zoom factor, like if you zoom on a map for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The wx.Panel does not support this feature out of the box. The FloatCanvas widget does support panning and zooming though. You could use that widget instead. Of course, I think you will have to draw the items on it instead of using regular widgets.

Comment: Would it be difficult to implement zooming ? Could we redefine the `OnPaint` of this Panel in order to zoom in/out ? (but even if this is possible, would this have an influence on the children widgets?)

Comment: I don't know, but I don't think adding zooming is going to be trivial. You should ask on the wxPython Google group to be sure though.